# Optimizing rank computation for very large sparse matrices

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have a sparse matrix such as

```
A =

   (1,1)        1
   (3,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (2,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (3,3)        1
   (4,3)        1
   (4,4)        1
```

The full matrix of `A` can see look like as following:

```
full(A) =

     1     1     1     0
     0     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1
```

I want to find the rank of matrix `A` by fast way(because my matrix can extend to 10000 x 20000). I try to do it by two ways but it give the different result

1. Convert to full matrix and find rank using

   ```
   rank(full(A)) = 3
   ```
2. Find the rank using sprank

   ```
   sprank(A) = 4
   ```

The true answer must be 3 that means using first way. However, it take long time to find the rank,especially matrix with large size. I know the reason why the second way give 4 because `sprank` only tells you how many rows/columns of your matrix have non-zero elements, while rank is reporting the actual rank of the matrix which indicates how many rows of your matrix are linearly independent. `sprank(A)` is 4 but `rank(A)` is only 3 because you can write the third row as a linear combination of the other rows, specifically `A(2,:) - A(1,:)`.

**My problem is that how to find the rank of a sparse matrix with lowest time consumption**

Update: I tried to use some way. However, it reported larger time consumption

```
%% Create random matrix
 G = sparse(randi(2,1000,1000))-1;
 A=sparse(G) %% Because my input matrix is sparse matrix
 %% Measure performance
>> tic; rank(full(A)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.710750 seconds.
>> tic; svds(A); toc
Elapsed time is 1.130674 seconds.
>> tic; eigs(A); toc
Warning: Only 3 of the 6 requested eigenvalues converged. 
> In eigs>processEUPDinfo at 1472
  In eigs at 365
Elapsed time is 4.894653 seconds.
```

Comment: have you tried using `eigs` finding number of non-zero eigen-values?

Comment: It take long time sir.

Comment: Does `svds(A)` work faster? The rank would be the number of nonzeros in the result (up to some tolerance to allow for numerical errors)

Comment: I reported bigger computational time than rank function

Comment: for small matrices (4x4) `full( rank( A ))` should indeed be faster. However, you will find it very difficult when the matrices are larger, e.g., 10000 x 20000.

Comment: @user3051460 `svds(A)` is a little faster than `rank(full(A))` on my machine for `A = sparse(randi(2,1000,1000))-1`. Another possibility would be `[a b] = lu(A)`. That's even faster on my machine.

Comment: @user3051460 Or `[a b] = qr(A)`. From that you could perhaps obtain the rank (I'm not sure how)

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia it appears that the LU decomposition is not accurate for this task, and the QR one should be preferred. The links to some resources can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRQR_factorization

Comment: OK. I test all possible way. However, it takes long time to find rank of matrix. Let see my report in my update question

Comment: `sprank` is the fast default method provided by Matlab and that was giving the incorrect answer. You could probably write a whole thesis on this topic. Optimizing rank computation for very large sparse matrices? Your question might be more appropriate on math exchange (http://math.stackexchange.com/). Here's something that may help: http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Guillaume.Dumas/Publications/sparseeliminationCASC2002.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which algorithm is best suited for you and I agree that may be more appropriate to ask on math.stackexchange.com. While I was trying with the random matrix you supply `G = sparse(randi(2,1000,1000))-1;` I noticed that there is little chance that its rank is <1000, and whatever algorithm you use, it is likely that its performance is very data-dependant. For instance using `eigs(G)` on a 2000-samples square matrix of rank (resp.) [198,325,503,1026,2000] yields the following performance (in seconds): [0.64,0.90,1.38,1.57,4.00] which shows the performance of the eigs function is strongly related with the rank of the matrix.

I also searched for existing tools and gave a try to [spnrank](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/singular/matrices/software/SJsingular/Doc/spnrank.pdf) which I think is not so data-dependant (it gives a better performance than eigs for high ranks and worse if the rank is small).

In the end you may want to adapt your technical solution depending on the kind of matrices you are most likely to work with.